# My sql table data doesn't move to my other mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a simple email verification,I have created everything,mail is also send to user but when we click on passkey data from temporarily members cannot send to my database table users Just a blank page appear Here's my code

```
<?php
include('config.php');

// Passkey that got from link 
$passkey = $_GET['passkey'];

$tbl_name1 = "temp_members_db";

// Retrieve data from table where row that match this passkey 
$sql1    = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

// If successfully queried 
if ($result1) {

    // Count how many row has this passkey
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result1);


    // if found this passkey in our database, retrieve data from 
    // table "temp_members_db"
    if ($count == 1) {

        $rows        = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
        $username    = $rows['username'];
        $email       = $rows['email'];
        $password    = $rows['password'];
        $avatar      = $rows['avatar'];
        $signup_date = $rows['signup_date'];
        $tbl_name2   = "users";

        // Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into   
        // table "users" 
        $sql2    = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name2 (username, password, email, avatar,  
  signup_date)VALUES 
  ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$avatar', '$signup_date)";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    }

    // if not found passkey, display message "Wrong Confirmation code" 
    else {
        echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
    }

    // if successfully moved data from table"temp_members_db" to   
    // table "users" displays message "Your account has been activated" and 
    // don't forget to delete confirmation code from   
    // table "temp_members_db"
    if ($result2) {

        echo "Your account has been activated";

        // Delete information of this user from table "temp_members_db"   
        // that has this passkey 
        $sql3    = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
        $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Missing a quote `'$signup_date)` - `mysql_error()` would have caught the syntax error.

Comment: What's all this though `table "users" displays message "Your account has been activated" and 
   don't forget to delete confirmation code from   
  table "temp_members_db"`? and `table "temp_members_db"`? Or, was that supposed to be commented out?

Comment: I just beautified his code, I think that was a comment.

Comment: I have created all table of showing on my code they are of same value collation and everything same

Comment: In that case, use PHP to echo all of your SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You missed a quote** in $sql2.
It should be:

```
('$username', '$password', '$email', '$avatar', '$signup_date')";
```

and you implemented:

```
('$username', '$password', '$email', '$avatar', '$signup_date)";
```

**Some tips:**
You should put a error_reporting at the front of your PHP file to make sure the code has no syntax error. If you see a blank page, there will be 80% possibility your syntax of your SQL command has error.

For some debug tips, you can copy the command and use echo to output, if you don't see the error, copy the code and paste it on phpMyAdmin and execute it. You will know where you are doing wrong.